# Is "scraping" a URL address or header metadata legal?

Tags: web-scraping

As far as I understand it, scraping website content, especially if scraping of content is explicitly forbidden in the ToC is illegal.

1. My question is what if I manually copy URLs from the browser and save it in a database for later analysis or whatever e.g. craigslist postings. Is this legal?
2. What if I write an app where I would manually copy/paste craigslist URLs and it would extract only the metadata from the header e.g. the Title or metatags and save that to a database, would that be legal since metadata is technically not content... or is it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question, not programming.

Comment: The cutting-and-pasting of a URL is obviously not illegal--that's what bookmarks are. The response of a server is its content--it doesn't matter if it's rendered visually in the browser or not (e.g., a hidden div or JS code). If you have a specific question about a specific website's specific content you need to contact *them*, not ask for legal advice on SO, which is for programming questions.

Comment: It's not illegal but they can sue you if they catch you. A US judge recently ruled that LinkedIn can't sue users for scraping their data so it would probably get tossed out.